# how to write HTTPS route in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have written the Route in RouteConfig.cs in MVC4. It's working fine with HTTP; i.e:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

How can I create HTTPS Route so that some pages can open on HTTPS and some pages on HTTP?

Comment: HTTPS has nothing with routes, it is how your IIS is set up. Maybe to have two different MVC 4 applications?

Answer (score 2):

As @SLaks suggested, you could decorate your `Action` with the `[RequireHttps]` attribute.

However, if you don't want to force Https on your `Action` but only require that the **`Route`** will match Https requests only, try to add a `RouteConstraint` as follows:

```
public class RequireHttpsConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return httpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
routes.MapRoute("SecuredPlaceOrder",
        "/PlaceOrderSecured",
        new { controller = "Orders", action = "PlaceOrder" },
        new { requireSSL = new RequireHttpsConstraint() }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

MVC routes only match the path portion of the URL.
They are completely independent of host or protocol.

If you want to restrict some URLs to HTTPS only, add the `[RequireHttps]` attribute to the controller or action.

Comment: Additional to this, it is most clean situation to have either HTTPS or HTTP. It is not good practice to switch from one to another.